# Ant + run a target if file exists

Tags: ant

I need to run another task only if java files are present in a location. I have searched for the same and came across something like the below:

```
<target name="check-abc">
<available file="abc.txt" property="abc.present"/>
```

`</target>`

`<target name="do-if-abc" depends="check-abc" if="abc.present">`
    ...
`</target>`

However in my situation, the file path is not fixed. I am having a directory with many sub directories and files. If java files are present in any of those locations, the property should set and run the second target. Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My example uses a [custom script condition](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html), implemented in groovy.

```
<project name="build" default="build">

    <path id="build.path">
        <pathelement location="lib/groovy-all-2.1.0-rc-1.jar"/>
    </path>

    <condition property="java.found">
        <scriptcondition language="groovy" value="false" classpathref="build.path">
            def ant = new AntBuilder()

            ant.fileset(id:"javaFiles", dir:"src", includes:"**/*.java")

            ant.project.references.javaFiles.each {
                self.value = true
            }
        </scriptcondition>
    </condition>

    <target name="build" if="java.found">
        <echo message="Found java files"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Alternatively you could write a custom java condition, which avoids the need to embed a scripting language within your build.

- [Custom conditions](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/custom-programming.html#customconditions)
- The [groovy-all](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.codehaus.groovy%7Cgroovy-all%7C2.1.0-rc-1%7Cjar) jar is available from Maven central. You can use [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to download it at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I worked out a solution for this one, but you're going to need [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) to make it work.

```
<target name="check-abc" depends="defineAntContribTasks">
    <path id="foo">
        <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <for param="some.file">
        <path refid="foo"/>
        <sequential>
            <echo message="checking @{some.file}"/>
            <property name="abc.present" value="true"/>
        </sequential>
    </for>
    <echo message="present = ${abc.present}"/>
</target>

<target name="do-if-abc" depends="check-abc" if="abc.present">
    <!-- whatever -->
</target>
```

You can probably ditch the echo statements; they're mostly so you can see what's being checked.

Comment: Im getting the following error with this. Problem: failed to create task or type for
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.

Comment: You have to define the antContrib tasks in your build, hence the use of `depends="defineAntContribTasks"` in the code I posted.  The front page of the [ant contrib web site](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) describes how to do this.

Comment: Im using other ant contrib tasks in this build explicitly. Do i need to define it as another target for this to work? pls advice

Comment: Wherever you're definint the ant-contrib tasks is fine, so long as they're brought into the build before the target I drew up runs.  I usually do this in a target named "defineAntContribTasks", so if you're defining them in a target, make the check-abc target depend on that.